# Is it possible to find the objects and DLL which a website is locking when running in Visual Studio or IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is it possible to find the objects and DLL which a website is locking when running in Visual Studio or IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see what objects, DLLs and other files are locked by any process (including Visual Studio or IIS) by using a tool such as [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).  For IIS you will want to view the file handles that are open for w3wp.exe or dllhost.exe, depending on what version of IIS you are using.  With Visual Studio you will want to inspect the devenv.exe process.

There is a nice search feature in Process Explorer that will be useful if you know the name of the file you suspect is being locked in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The SysInternals suite contains lots of useful tools for this sort of thing - see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx

> Process Explorer
>
> Find out what files, registry keys and other objects processes have open, which DLLs they have loaded, and more. This uniquely powerful utility will even show you who owns each process.
>
> Process Monitor
>
> Monitor file system, Registry, process, thread and DLL activity in real-time.